# How to copy sequential files in Ubuntu

Tags: linux, image, ubuntu, directory, copy

The software I've written makes videos from images. However, before it makes the video, it has to create images from other images. Many of these images match. So, to save processing power and speed up the creation of the final videos, I want to make a copy of all frames that match. The flow is:

1. If the image is unique, save it to disk as 'image-number.png'.
2. If the image is not unique, save the image number in a List.
3. When a new unique image is found, copy the image of the last image number up to the number that is represented by this unique.

For instance, if my image number is 0, I would obviously save that image to disk. If the next image number of a unique image is 10, then I would copy images 1 through 9 from image 0 before saving image 10.

This works well on my Windows instances. The way I do it in Windows is like this:

```
String cmd = "CMD /C for /l %f in (" + (frameToCopy + 1) + ",1," + (sameImageList.size() + (frameToCopy)) + ") do copy \"" +
                    outputFileName + fileName +"_" + frameToCopy + ".png\" \"" +
                    outputFileName + fileName + "_" + "%f.png\"";
```

I then pass the above to a Process which invokes the command line and have sped up my video creation by an order of magnitude when creating large videos. I'm sure there's a similar command in Ubuntu, however, as I search around, I can't seem to find precisely what I'm trying to do via searching here or elsewhere. Can a Linux expert give me a little assistance please?

EDIT FOR CLARITY
I am sorry for any confusion with my question. I am making these images with software I wrote - using the Java programming language. Each time my Java program sees a unique image, it saves that image to disk. Each time it sees a repeat of the same image, it just stores the image number in a List. Then, the next time it sees a unique image, it makes a copy of that last image up to the number represented by the new unique image. I am using a Process object to do this. The String representation of the command I posted is what I am doing in Windows and am looking for a command that does the exact same thing in Unix based systems.

Comment: Thanks for adding the ubuntu tag. I tried that myself but don't have enough rep yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I find your question quite unclear, but think the following may help. Let's say you have frame zero and the next unique frame is frame 8. So as I understand it, you need to copy frame zero and save as frame 1-7. You can do this in `bash` with

```
#!/bin/bash
for i in {1..7}
do
    cp frame_0.png frame_$i.png
done
```

Or, if the files are really identical, you do not need to store them multiple times, you can simply create symbolic links that just point to the same lump of data on disk like this:

```
for i in {1..7}
do
    ln -s frame_0.png frame_$i.png
done
```